# MIPS removing a +one from an inner loop?

Tags: assembly, optimization, mips

I am looking at this sample problem: 3∑b=1  3∑a=1(a+b+1)
and I was given a sample code on the correct way to solve it using mips. I was wondering how I will be able to remove the (+1) from this code? I been playing with it for over an hour and I still don't get when the (+1) is added.

```
.text
.globl main

main:
     li $t0,1
     li $t1,1

loopb:
     beq $t1, 4, loopa
     add $t2, $t1, $t0
     addi $t2, $t2, 1
     add $t3, $t3, $t2
     addi $t1, $t1, 1
     j loopb
loopa:
     addi $t0, $t0, 1
     beq $t0, 4, end
     li $t1, 1 
     j loopb

end:
    move $a0, $t3
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

In some circumstances, if you can determine how many times it loops — let's say N times — you can substitute *+1 inside the loop* with *+N outside the loop*.

Here we know that the inner loop will repeat 3 times, so +1 inside the inner loop can be substituted for +3 outside the inner loop.  (Moving something out of the inner loop means placing it within the outer loop (only).)

Further, if you also know that the outer loop goes M times, then you can move the addition of N (that we place in the outer loop as per above) to outside of the outer loop by adding +N*M instead (just once).

---

Let's also note that this code fails to initialize `$t3` (like to 0) at the beginning.  (As an aside, it is too bad that the common simulators initialize all the registers to 0 — because of this many initialization errors are not seen.  It would be better in my opinion if the simulators used some garbage-like value instead, e.g. 0xBAD00BAD, so programmer would catch such errors during testing.)

---

Since the code, inside the inner loop, is repeatedly adding the outer loop control variable, that addition also can be substituted with a single multiplication outside of the inner loop, and so on..

Comment: Thank You! But I do have a question. How will this code look like if the problem was 3∑b=1 3∑a=1(a+b)?

Comment: There are three `addi`'s.  Two are for loop control variables, and one for the +1 in the formula.  The way the code is structured, the very first `addi` is for the formula.